# Angular 8 [html2canvas Library] - How to get a screenshot without opening new window?

Tags: angular

I've a Angular 8 project installed html2canvas.The way now is to open a new page and take a screenshot.
The way I hope is to not open any page and take a screenshot.is there any way to achieve that?

**Parent Ts => focus on this window when child window opened.**

```
 openNewLink(){
     let url = "testUrl";
     window.open(url, "_blank");
 }
```

**Child Ts => Worked in background.**

```
screenshot(){
  html2canvas(this.screen.nativeElement).then(canvas => {
    let base64Text = canvas.toDataURL();
    this.Service.passBase64(base64Text).subscribe((res: ApiResult) => {
      window.close();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: want to dowload it as a file?

Comment: I want to get base64 string and passing to service.

Comment: So you want to make a screenshot when a button is clicked?

Comment: Show us whar have you try